# Why is there a huge big gap between the back button and the starting element of the view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is how my view looks like on simulator
[image]

I don't understnad how this huge gap comes. This is how my view starts

```
NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Mandatory Fields")){
                        TextField("First name", text: $identifyingData.firstName)
                            .autocapitalization(.words)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
....
```

This is the code that calls the above view

```
.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction){
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyView(myData: .constant(MyData.empty))){
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you have by any chance a view that is pushed from embedded in NavigationView?

Comment: @Stefan I pasted the piece of code that calls the view in the question.

Comment: And what happens in MyView? I've tried your code with `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` and it doesn't have any gap https://ibb.co/vPH2xh5

Comment: @Stefan yes (random text to exceed minimum char limit)

Comment: Can you share the code for a view that this screenshot is pushed from?

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that you have both view wrapped inside of `NavigationView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was enable to reproduce your problem after realizing that your pushed view is also embedded in the `NavigationView`. Just extract your pushed view outside of NavigationView and problem will be solved. Works for me.

Root view:

```
struct FirstTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: FormsView()) {
                Text("Push me")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pushed view:

```
struct FormsView: View {
    
    @State var txt = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Mandatory Fields")){
                    TextField("First name", text: $txt)
                        .autocapitalization(.words)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: img]

Comment: I was scratching my head with this one at first, but here I was adding another NavigationView inside a screen that already pushed a NavigationView which accounts for the extra padding on the top. Removing NavigationView from the screen I was pushing to solved my issue. Thanks!